# Merge dataframes based on two columns and a where clause

Tags: pandas

I am trying to mimic a conditional LEFT OUTER SQL join in pandas like the following:

```
SELECT sha256_cpn
, rank
FROM cr_df
LEFT JOIN be_df
ON cr_df.sha256_cpn = be_df.sha256_cpn
AND rank = 1
```

In more general terms, I have a many-to-many connection with multiple sha256_cpn records in `cr_df` and multiple in `be_df` and I want to join the `be_df` records only to the first `rank` record, but keep the rest of the records on the primary table. Is this possible?

Example of records in `cr_df`:

```
sha256_cpn | rank | etc. columns
1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 1 | ...
1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 2 | ...
1005a9eaf26b44bfd70b6430f1e86fd14add9b042d4383b6f6fcb6549e5360cb | 3 | ...
```

Here is my code:

```
// sha256_cpn Object
// rank Integer

cr_df[cr_df['rank']==1].merge(be_df, how='left', on=['sha256_cpn'])
```

Which achieves the join, but obviously filters out those records with `rank`'s that are greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correct, you are fine with the merge you generated but some rows a missing for the correct result.

So I would say you can create your result by appanding the missing rows.

```
cr_df[cr_df['rank']==1].merge(be_df, how='left', on=['sha256_cpn']).append(cr_df[cr_df['rank']!=1])
```

To make it even more general, you can define a `rule` as a variable.

```
rule = cr_df['rank']==1
cr_df[rule].merge(be_df, how='left', on=['sha256_cpn']).append(cr_df[~rule])
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I had wanted it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the primary Dataframe before merging it.

```
cr_df1 = cr_df
```

And after the merge, use the duplicated dataframe for filtering the ranks other than 1.

```
cr_df1 = cr_df1[cr_df1['rank']!=1]
```

Comment: You have to be careful with the way you are making a copy. To make sure you have a copy and not a pointer to a variable you have to write `cr_df.copy()` elsewise you can get some trouble.